# KIF - tests failed on Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, kif-framework

My app pass all KIF tests on Xcode 7.2. But after I upgrade to Xcode 7.3 it all get fail.
Reason : App is not coming to foreground during tests on Xcode 7.3
But if I manually click on the app and take into foreground then all good. 
So I assume there is no issue with the test cases.

If anyone has has encounter anything similar and has a solution please let know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

by manually clicking it will build a previous 7.2 build not 7.3 .clean the code and build again it will work.